# Can't Get Email from Facebook Login

Tags: facebook-login

I am working on putting Facebook login on my site. I'm not a very strong javascript coder, but usually find the code I need and, after some work and trial and error, get the results I need.

I got the login script working and the only thing I need (I think--remember javascript isnt my strong point so maybe you see some flaws here that I don't) is to obtain the email address from the login call. I have added 'email' to the scope and tried to access email from the response object as well as the user object. I know that email is valid because I am testing with my FB account and it was validated with email, not phone. But it comes up as undefined.

You'll see the spot where I am trying to get it in the myfacebooklogin function.

Anyone know how/why I cant access the email?
Also, does this code look solid?
Lastly, how would you best handle the session/state? In ASP (what the site is coded in--classic, not .NET) I use the session object if the person logged in traditionally. If they log out, I just set the session variable to "".But with this, would you just authenticate every page and use that as the session, or would you use the FB login to create an ASP session and use that?

Below is all of the code. The only other pieces are in the HTML body--a button to the myfacebooklogin function and a div that gets written to (which was part of the code I found so I left it in).

Thanks!

```
<script>

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));



  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'myAppId',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
  });




  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  //second parameter of FB.getLoginStatus is "true" to force a roundtrip to FB.
  //if "true" not set, result will come from cache
  //set "true" only when needed to save performance (for example, on login page)

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  },true);
  };



  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      //testAPI();
alert('1');
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
alert('2');

    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
alert('3');

    }
  }



function myFacebookLogin() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       alert(response.name);
       alert(response.id);
       //alert(response.mail);
     });


      // FB.api('/me', function(user) {
      //  console.log(user.name + ': ' + user.email);
      //  alert(user.email);
      // });


    } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
   }, {scope: 'public_profile, email', return_scopes: true});  //scope: 'publish_actions'


}

</script>
```

Comment: I got it. Two things I did, not sure which (or both) solved it. 1) Made the app live. 2) Added: {fields:'id,name,email'} to the FB.api call so it looks as follows: FB.api('/me', {fields:'id,name,email'}, function(response)

Comment: But I'd still love feedback by any good java coders to let me know if this looks solid to you, if I missed anything... and how you would handle state/session.

Answer (score 2):

You need pass the fields in the url `"/me"` like:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=name,id,email', function(response) {
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you, please, tell me where I can read about it in the official documentation?

Comment: @Velidan, i think this is an unsuported method to get the email and infos, but,in my case, still works, the official documentation suggest to use another way:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/

Comment: Thank you Luann =) I was wondering how did you know about it)

Comment: Thank you very much! I break my head two days